# Salesforce static resource image upload via Mule4 not displaying

Tags: static-resources, images, mulesoft, salesforce-connect

I have to upload images to static resources via mule 4. The code works fine without any error but the image not displaying in salesforce static resource. I'm getting 200 responses instead of 201. When I add the same image and data manually it is adding to static resource and displaying properly. Can someone help me to find out the reason for this?

I used salesforce create connector version 10.12.4. The image comes from a form. When I stored that image in a local drive it's working fine. This is the config,

```
<salesforce:create doc:name="Create" doc:id="2349b3aa-06f8-561-9e6e-8c53b01d4579" config-ref="Salesforce_Config" type="StaticResource">
    </salesforce:create>
```

Comment: What is the actual content of the Static Resource after you attempt to perform this operation? You can download and inspect it.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks for the suggestion, David. I'm still new to this. Can I know how to get that content from salesforce? I'm not getting any error type on my side.

Comment: You can navigate to Static Resources under Salesforce Setup. They’re zip files, even if not named as such.

Comment: @DavidReed mm.. I can't see any record after the operation (no any raw related to it ). So can't see the content of it. But I'm not getting any errors either. When I do the same data manually it is uploaded properly. I just want to find the reason for the not uploading image.

Comment: Could you provide more details regarding your configuration in Mule 4?

Comment: @FelixvanHove I updated the config related to the connector.

Comment: I lack the experience with this, but would you not use `<salesforce:create-metadata>` (see [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.14/salesforce-connector-reference#createMetadata))?